# How to place tables on page

Tags: html, css

I have 4 tables and submit button
[image: 4 tables and submit button]

How can i place them more compactive

maybe like this:
[image: oh]

this is my html code

```
<body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/form.py" id="myform">
        <table class="table-fill">
            ...
        </table>

        <table class="table-fill">
            ...
        </table>
     ...
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="add"  value="Submit" form="myform"/> 
    </form>
</body>
```

this is my table style

```
.table-fill {
background: white;
border-radius:3px;
border-collapse: collapse;
height: 120px;
margin: auto;
max-width: 100px;
padding:5px;
}
```

my submit style

```
input[type=submit] {
    padding:10px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: You can place every two tables inside a huge div with two columns.

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

A way can be to simply use `display: inline-block` on your table style and adjust margins

```css
.table-fill {
 display: inline-block;
  
  background: white;
  border-radius:3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: 1px solid #000;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding:10px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="table-fill">block 1</div>
<div class="table-fill">block 2</div>
<div class="table-fill">block 3</div>
<div class="table-fill">block 4</div>
<div class="table-fill">block 5</div>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Or make a container and use `flex` that will be much more easy to auto center tables :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius:3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: 1px solid #000;
  height: 120px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding:10px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-fill">block 1</div>
  <div class="table-fill">block 2</div>
  <div class="table-fill">block 3</div>
  <div class="table-fill">block 4</div>
  <div class="table-fill">block 5</div>
</div>
<input type="submit"/>
```